# How to get elementsByClassName and then inside getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm rewriting a script from jQuery to pure JS and I don't know how else could i write this.I want to get attribute of element inside class 'form-basket' with id 'przecenajs' I know getElementsByClassName returns object of elements, and that's probably why I get the error:**document.getElementsByClassName(...).getElementById is not a function**
 but I'm not into JS that much so i might be wrong

```
 price =   document.getElementsByClassName('form-basket').getElementById("przecenajs").getAttribute("data-procent");
```

Comment: *"and that's probably why I get the error"* it is.

Comment: Is missing the most important part: **The Error** :-)

Comment: Maybe splitting that one line over multiple different function calls will help you debug and get what you want.

Comment: document.querySelector should be your friend

Comment: What about `document.querySelector()`?

Comment: My fault ;)  fixed

Comment: Forget about the classnames, IDs should be unique so you can just use `document.getElementById("przecenajs").getAttribute("data-procent")`.

Comment: Id's should be unique, so in theory you should be able to use `document.getElementById("przecenajs");` also getElementsByClassName returns an htmlcollection wich has no getelementById method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` object.

You probably want to use `querySelector` function:

```
document.querySelector('.form-basket #przecenajs')
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.form-basket #przecenajs').getAttribute("data-procent"));
```

```html
<div class='form-basket'>
  <div id='przecenajs' data-procent="Hello!">
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```
document.getElementById('przecenajs')
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('przecenajs').getAttribute("data-procent"));
```

```html
<div class='form-basket'>
  <div id='przecenajs' data-procent="Hello!">
  </div>
</div>
```

## Resources

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: It works good, until I put getAttribute at the end, then i get null

Comment: document.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: @WinithePooh that happens because the `querySelector` didn't found the element.

Comment: My id is deeper than just right inside .form-basket

Comment: @WinithePooh share your HTML... :-)

Comment: Your way works, my colleague changed the structure of html, that's why It didn't work. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to select the form-basket first. Since IDs should only be used once inside a document, you can simply selct by id like so:

```
document.getElementById("przecenajs").getAttribute("data-procent");
```

Comment: While this is the truth, it does not explain why the OP gets an error when including the non-needed bit.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are searching for more than only one tag, because if you wouldn't you could just use `document.getElementById()` so I think these lines do the job you want, you have to manually create the list with all the attributes to replicate the jquery behaviour:

```
var priceList = [];
document.querySelectorAll(".form-basket #przecenajs").forEach( (element) =>{
    priceList.push(element.getAttribute("data-procent"));
});
```